# Standard SQL Date Functioning

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to migrate to Standard SQL and read some of the documentation about the date functions but I'm still a bit confused as to how to perform a certain query.

My current legacy SQL query is below:

## legacySQL

```
select
date,
round(sum(revenue_total),2) as revenue
from [project:dataset.table]
where month(date) = month(date_add(current_date(),-1,'month'))
group by 1
```

How would I convert the where statement to a standard SQL query?

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to make this ANSI SQL compliant?  If so, I think `EXTRACT` is what you want:  `extract(month from <date column>`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) = DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)
```

I suspect that your `date` column is actually of type `TIMESTAMP`, in which case you need to convert to a `DATE` first:

```
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM date), MONTH) = DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)
```

Note that the `EXTRACT` function has an optional `AT TIME ZONE` clause, which lets you specify the time zone to use if you don't want to use the default, which is UTC. See the [timestamp function documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#extract) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the date functions at hand, there are equivalent functions in [BG's standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions)

- MONTH() -> EXTRACT(): `EXTRACT(part FROM date_expression)`, e.g.

  ```
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)
  ```
- `date_add()` and `current_date()` are still available.

Answer (score 0):

Follow an example using GitHub public repository:

```
SELECT
  CAST(committer.date AS DATE),
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
WHERE
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST(committer.date AS DATE)) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))

GROUP BY
  1
LIMIT
  10
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you really want:

```
where date_trunc(date, 'month') = date_add(date_trunc(current_date), interval -1 month)
```

However, what you have written doesn't take the year into account, so it would be:

```
where extract(month from date) = extract(month from current_date) - 1
```